# Internet Explorer crash when using Gmail

Tags: gmail, internet-explorer-11

I have a user trying to compose an email in Gmail but IE stops working and recovers the page whenever the main body of the email is selected from the compose page.

IE was previously crashing when trying to send but this was fixed by placing google.com in compatability mode.

Comment: Typically GMail should work just fine with IE 11.  You may want to have  your system scanned for malware and/or viruses.

Comment: Try with all add-ons disabled or simply start [IE in `Safe Mode`](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN265764/EN)

Comment: And here i was expecting unhelpful snarky posts to take IE outside and shoot it

Comment: @IG_42 Not everyone hates IE "just because", and saying "switch to another bowser" is not a solution when it should work fine. ;)